# Is there a way to make vim display "virtual characters" before/after regular patterns in the buffer?

Tags: vim

Vim has `list` and `listchars` options that make vim display "virtual characters" (by which I mean characters that aren't actually in the buffer) in certain situations. For example, you can make trailing spaces look like something else, or add a visible character to represent the newline character.

I'd like to be able to enable the display of certain characters either before or after certain regular patterns ((perhaps syntax items). Sort of like syntax highlighting, but instead of just changing the color/styling of characters that are in the buffer, I'd like to display extra characters that aren't in the buffer.

For example, I'd like to display a virtual `:` (colon) after all occurrences of the word "`where`" that appear at the end of a line.

Is this possible, and if so, what is the necessary vimscript to do it?

Comment: You want to look at the conceal feature (`:h conceal`). However I have no idea if this allow you to do what you want.

Comment: @FDinoff Thanks. If I don't get any answers to this question then that is probably the first avenue I will explore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a use case for the *conceal* feature added in Vim 7.3 (`:help :syn-conceal`). However, it is distinct from `:set list`:

- it is part of syntax highlighting, so you need to augment any existing syntax (e.g. via `:autocmd Syntax * ...`), and there is potential for interference
- you can hide or replace one or more characters with a single conceal character; so, if there's a whitespace after the `where` in your example, you can turn that into a `:`, but **you can't *add* a virtual character**, and this won't work at all for a `where` at the end of the line
- you also need to tweak the `'conceallevel'` and `'concealcursor'` options to get listchars-like behavior

So, it won't be easy and totally consistent with `:set list`; think hard whether you really need this feature. (You didn't tell what this is for, hinting at the [XY problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).)

For a "perfect" implementation, you'd have to modify Vim's source code, to add an additional `'listchars'` option.

Comment: I think you are correct. I think there is no way to do exactly what I want in vim as-is. syn-conceal is pretty interesting, though.